# AWS dynamoDB quick start not working - Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

This is my first attempt with dynamoDB, I'm following the below quickstart guide.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/gettingstartedguide/GettingStarted.Download.html

I'm getting an error when executing this terminal command

```
java -Djava.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -inMemory
```

Unfortunately I know nothing about java but this is required to run the python SDK

This is the error that is produced.

```
Initializing DynamoDB Local with the following configuration:
Port:   8000
InMemory:   true
DbPath: null
SharedDb:   true
shouldDelayTransientStatuses:   false
CorsParams: *

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/logging/log4j/spi/ExtendedLogger : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:637)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:141)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.shared.logging.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:28)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.server.DynamoDBProxyServer.<clinit>(DynamoDBProxyServer.java:36)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner.createServer(ServerRunner.java:124)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner.createServerFromCommandLineArgs(ServerRunner.java:120)
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.local.main.ServerRunner.main(ServerRunner.java:71)
```

Any ideas on what this error could be about

Answer (score 1):

Update to the latest jdk/jre. Install java 8 in your machine and set it as default.